# How to join a date to date ranges in Pandas?

Tags: date, pandas, time-series

I have one table with dates and another table where there is rather weekly data. My weeks start at Tuesday and the second table's date is supposed to determine the week (basically the Tuesday before the date is the start of the week; alternatively that date is an example day in that week).

How can I join the dates to information about weeks?

Here is the setup:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([dt(2016,2,3), dt(2016,2,8), dt(2016,2,9), dt(2016,2,15)])

df_week=pd.DataFrame([(dt(2016,2,4),"a"), (dt(2016,2,11),"b")], columns=["week", "val"])
# note the actual start of the weeks are the Tuesdays: 2.2., 9.2.

# I expect a new column df["val"]=["a", "a", "b", "b"]
```

I've seen pandas `date_range`, but I cannot see how to do that from there.

Comment: So did `DatetimeIndex.asof` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [DatetimeIndex.asof](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.asof.html):

This will give you the closest index up to the day in `df`:

```
df_week.set_index('week', inplace=True)
df_week.index.asof(df['day'][1])
```

You can now use it to select the corresponding value:

```
df_week.loc[df_week.index.asof(df['day'][1])]
```

Finally, apply it to the entire dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dt(2016,2,8), dt(2016,2,9), dt(2016,2,15)], columns=['day'])
df['val'] = df.apply(lambda row: df_week.loc[df_week.index.asof(row['day'])]['val'], axis=1)
```

I removed the first value from `df` because I didn't want to deal with edge cases.

Result:

```
         day val
0 2016-02-08   a
1 2016-02-09   a
2 2016-02-15   b
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to do what expected. Meanwhile I had used a pure-Python version, but `asof` will be useful frequently. Note that my week doesn't actually start on the dates given, but on Tuesdays.